# Laravel - query where last two are equal to

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query where I need to check if the last two rows have the column `answered` equal to string 'not'. That is the condition for the if loop in my controller:

```
$inactive = Answer::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->where('answered', 'not')
                            ->where('player_id', $player->id)
                            ->where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)
                            ->take(2);

if ($inactive) {
                // The game was finished
                $opponent = $quiz->getOpponent($player);
                $quiz->status = 'finished';
                $quiz->save();

                Event::fire(new GameEvent(
                    'quizFinished',
                    [
                        $opponent->user,
                        $player->user,
                    ],
                    []
                ));
            }
```

But it is not working as I expected since the if loop is being entered even when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a very small mistake

```
$inactive = Answer::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->where('answered', 'not')
                            ->where('player_id', $player->id)
                            ->where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)
                            ->take(2)
                            ->get();
```

Notice the `->get()`.

Without that, the `$inactive` is still an eloquent object. which means that it is not null.

Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

Answer (score 0):

```
$inactive = Answer::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            //->where('answered', 'not')
                            ->where('player_id', $player->id)
                            ->where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)
                            ->take(2);

if ($inactive->count() == 2 && $inactive->first()->answered == 'not' && $inactive->last()->answered == 'not') {
                // The game was finished
                $opponent = $quiz->getOpponent($player);
                $quiz->status = 'finished';
                $quiz->save();

                Event::fire(new GameEvent(
                    'quizFinished',
                    [
                        $opponent->user,
                        $player->user,
                    ],
                    []
                ));
            }
```